# How to implement promise in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

> How to implement promise in nodejs? could anyone provide some examples
>   for implementation of this?
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.promisejs.org/) is always your friend. First example there is of a promise.

Comment: Promises are already implemended in NodeJS and current browsers

Comment: He's obviously a new SO user give him a break ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments on the original question. Docs explain very well. You can find more info [here (includes sample)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Or look at the example below.

```js
    const asyncThingWithPromise = () => {
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try{
           // do something async here. Like get data from a server or read a file from disk etc.
           var value = 'My Async Data'; 
           resolve(value) // handled by promise's then()
        }catch(error){
           reject(error) // handled by promise's catch()
        }
       });
      return promise;
    }


    // usage with then/catch
    asyncThingWithPromise()
      .then(value => console.log(value))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));



   // usage with async / await
   try{
    const value = await asyncThingWithPromise();
    console.log(value);
   }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much wickdninja for your help!

Comment: No problem. Good luck :)